# Could not install from "node_modules/eth-sig-util/ethereumjs-abi@git+https:/github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I deleted the `.next` and `node_modules` folder (just experimenting) and then tried executing `npm i`. I got the following error:

```
$ npm i
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "node_modules/eth-sig-util/ethereumjs-abi@git+https:/github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

Any resolution?

Answer (score 1):

So, the culprit was dirty `package-lock.json` file. I just reset my repo using `git reset --hard` so that the package-lock.json comes to the last working state. (PLEASE USE `git reset --hard` WITH CAUTION; advisable to stash the WIP using `git stash` first!)

After this, running `npm i` gave no error.

Answer (score 0):

look at this link.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-abi

You can use this command.

```
npm i ethereumjs-abi
```